# How to select background text if there was a div with position absolute in the document

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a red square div with position absolute.

but it doesn't allow text selection in the background surrounding it.

`Html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>You need to enable JavaScript to 
...more text..check example,,,...to run this app.You need to 
enable JavaScript to run this app.
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

`JS`

```
var mousePosition;
var offset = [0,0];
var div;
var isDown = false;

div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.position = "absolute";

div.style.left = "100px";
div.style.top = "100px";
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";

div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "blue";

document.body.appendChild(div);

div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [
        div.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
        div.offsetTop - e.clientY
    ];
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown = false;
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDown) {
        mousePosition = {
    
            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY
    
        };
        div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
        div.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);
```

I don't want to use z-index property.

Any idea how to do it? I just want to select the text surrounding the red square, not underneath the square. Thanks in advance

[Here is the Example](https://jsfiddle.net/blueseal/80nv6ydc/11/)

[image: can't select text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on `mousedown` if it's the same `div` which you need.
And when `mousemove`, call `event.preventDefault()` only if `isDown === true`:

```js
var mousePosition;
var offset = [0, 0];
var div;
var isDown = false;

div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.position = "absolute";

div.style.left = "100px";
div.style.top = "100px";
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";

div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "blue";

document.body.appendChild(div);

div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  isDown = true;
  offset = [
    div.offsetLeft - event.clientX,
    div.offsetTop - event.clientY
  ];
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  isDown = false;
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  if (isDown) {
    event.preventDefault(); /* <---- */
    mousePosition = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
    };
    div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
    div.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
  }
}, true);
```

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, appreciate your answer

Comment: ```if (event.target !== div) { /* <---- */
    return;
  }``` This check on `mousedown` is redundant, because this event is listening on the required `div` i.e. red square div. did I miss something? if it was listening on `document` then this check was necessary

Comment: Yes you're right. Some nonsense on my part, because the `div` is the same `div`. With your permission, removed this from the answer.

Comment: it's all fine. Have a nice day/night!

Comment: I just want to mention this, Your original solution allowed to select text inside the red square plus text in the background, so the original version was more accurate. thank you for your time.  sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: But no, the piece of code that I deleted does not make sense )) And so that the text in the red `<div>` does not selected, add `user-select: none;`